# How to Download Image from specific URL to Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am importing an image from my URL link. The link works fine in browser and I can see the image. But when I am trying to import it in Unity, it is completely blank. Why is this happening?

The image is a jpg.

```cs
public RawImage img;
public string url;

public void Start () {
        StartCoroutine (DownloadImage (url));
}

IEnumerator DownloadImage (string MediaUrl) {
        UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture (MediaUrl);
        yield return request.SendWebRequest ();
        if (request.isNetworkError || request.isHttpError)
            Debug.Log (request.error);
        else
            img.texture = ((DownloadHandlerTexture) request.downloadHandler).texture;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer this question, I suggest that in addition to solving the problem, you use the **Asynchronous** method instead of **IEnumerator**. Because it increases the flexibility of the code and can be active outside the time frames of Unity. Therefore, the code below is an image downloader that is very easy to use.

```cs
private async Task<Texture2D> DownloadImage(string MediaUrl) {
    
    var request = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(MediaUrl);
    request.SendWebRequest();
    while (!request.isDone) await Task.Yield(); // wait 1 frame until request done
    if (request.isNetworkError || request.isHttpError)
    {
        Debug.Log("Error: " + request.error); // Optinal: Call Errors
        return null;
    }
    return DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(request);
}
```

Now to use Async code, just add Await behind the method call.

```cs
private async void Start()
{
    image.texture = await DownloadImage(url); // Automatically wait until images download from link
}
```