# Unity Coroutine callback with dynamic type

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, generics

I can use callbacks with coroutines just fine but if I want to pass params into the callback then `System.Action` doesn't like my generic typing.

`cannot convert from 'System.Action<T>' to 'System.Action<UnityEngine.Texture2D>'`

```
public IEnumerator CoHttpGET<T>(string uri, System.Action<T> callback) {
    if(typeof(T) == typeof(Texture2D)) yield return WeatherTracker.instance.StartCoroutine(CoHttpGET_Texture(uri, callback));
    else 

    ... logic for other types
}
```

**Question**

How can I return a generic value through System.Action in this case ?

**Extra**

For now I'm doing the busy work of defining additional methods for all the types I need eg HttpGET_Texture, _json, _string, etc etc

Comment: Although you asked some questions together. But I am sure you will get most of the answers in this post that I answered some time ago. Thank you for upvoting if it helps. [Download_Image_Async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75833199/how-to-download-image-from-specific-url-to-unity3d/75837720#75837720)

Comment: why don't just call `CoHttpGET_Texture(uri, callback)` what purpose to use generic type ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for this case , I think just write like this enough.

```
CoHttpGET("http://123", (Texture2D tex2D)=>
{ 

});
CoHttpGET("http://123", (string tex2D) =>
{

});

public void CoHttpGET(string uri, System.Action<Texture2D> callback)
{
    Texture2D result = null;
    callback(result);
}

public void CoHttpGET(string uri, System.Action<string> callback)
{
    string result = null;
    callback(result);
}
```

Comment: overloads are the obvious answer, not sure why my brain refused to see that earlier.

Answer (score 1):

In general: You *could* rather use [`is`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/is) and include the type casting like

```
 if(callback is System.Action<Texture2D> textureCallback) yield return CoHttpGET_Texture(uri, textureCallback);
```

or even use pattern matching like e.g.

```
public IEnumerator CoHttpGET<T>(string uri, System.Action<T> callback) 
{
    switch(callback)
    {
        case System.Action<Texture2D> textureCallback:
            yield return CoHttpGET_Texture(uri, textureCallback);
            break;

        default:
            throw new ArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Btw note how you do not need to call the inner `StartCoroutine`. I assume since the outer one also returns `IEnumerator` you anyway already run this as a Coroutine so you can simply directly `yield return` another `IEnumerator`

---

**HOWEVER**, it would make a lot more sense to me though to rather prefer [**overloads**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75883751/7111561) in your use case